# ExtJs Paging ignores totalProperty

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I use ExtJs 4.1

My grid works OK but I am having problems to set up a proper paging. The paging toolbar gets the number of records and pages wrong.

The **server** has 8 rows in total, but returns only 4 as specified. So it should be 2 pages with 4 rows each.

**Json** of initial load looks like:

```
{
    "value": {
        "data": [{
                "id": "user1",
                "title": "index0"
            }, {
                "id": "user2",
                "title": "index1"
            }, {
                "id": "user3",
                "title": "index2"
            }, {
                "id": "user4",
                "title": "index3"
            }
        ],
        "total": 8,
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 2,
        "pagesize": "4"
    }
}
```

**Settings**:

```
nItemsPerPage = 4;
```

**Pagingtoolbar**:

```
var oPagingToolbar = Ext.create( 'Ext.toolbar.Paging', {
            store         : oStoreUsers,
            pageSize      : nItemsPerPage,
            dock          : 'bottom',
            displayInfo   : true
         } );
```

My **grid** has the store `oStoreUsers` and the paging toolbar docked.

**Store** is loaded:

```
// tried each of the following lines for loading
// none gave me 2 pages
oStoreUsers.load( { params: { start: 0, limit: nItemsPerPage } } );
oStoreUsers.loadPage( 1 );
oStoreUsers.loadPage( 1, { params: { start: 0, limit: nItemsPerPage } } );
```

The store has attributes like:

```
root: 'value.data',
pageSize: nItemsPerPage
```

**Problem**: The 4 rows are loaded into the store and displayed in the grid. 
However, the paging toolbar says `Page 1 of 1` and `Displaying 1 - 4 of 4`, when it should `Page 1 of 2` and `Displaying 1 - 4 of 8`.

How to get that to work?

---

Edit:

`reader`

```
   reader: {
           type         : 'json',
           root         : 'value.data',
           totalProperty: 'total'
        }
```

Comment: Post your proxy/reader config.

Comment: Did you mean the info in my edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your totalProperty is incorrect. Needs to be `value.total`.

Comment: OH MAN. I was going crazy on this. And now its just `value.total`. THANKS! ! !